# ¿Cómo puedo pasar el path obtenido mediante filechooser a un método en otra clase?

Tags: java, javafx, rutas

tengo el siguiente problema, en una aplicación en javafx tengo un método que selecciona mediante un filechooser un archivo determinado y obtiene la ruta. Hasta ahi bien, el problema viene cuando le paso la ruta a un metodo de otra clase para para que con esa ruta busque el archivo y lo lea, la ruta que pasa al otro método es tal que así "c:\users\directorio\archivo.txt".
Alguien tiene una ligera idea de como solucionar esto?
os paso el código de los dos métodos para que los veais.
Este es el código del filechooser:
private void AlertPrecios() {

```
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("SELECCIÓN DE PRECIOS");
    alert.setContentText("¿Desea utilizar una carta de precios difrente?");
    ButtonType okButton = new ButtonType("Yes", ButtonBar.ButtonData.YES);
    ButtonType noButton = new ButtonType("No", ButtonBar.ButtonData.NO);
    alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(okButton, noButton);
    alert.showAndWait().ifPresent((ButtonType type) -> {
        if (type == okButton) {
            String rutaArchivo = null;
            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
            File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

            if (file != null) {

                try {
                    rutaArchivo = file.getPath();
                    Path ruta = Paths.get(rutaArchivo);
                    System.out.println(ruta);
                    pizza.cargaPrecios(ruta);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Alert alert3 = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
                    alert3.setTitle("ERROR EN SELECCIÓN");
                    alert3.setHeaderText("NO HA SELECCIONADO NINGÚN ARCHIVO DE PRECIOS VÁLIDO");
                    alert3.setContentText("Se utilizarán los precios por defecto");
                    alert3.showAndWait();
                }

            } else if (type == noButton) {

                Alert alert2 = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
                alert2.setTitle("INFORMACIÓN");
                alert2.setHeaderText("NO HA SELECCIONADO NINGÚN ARCHIVO DE PRECIOS");
                alert2.setContentText("Se utilizarán los precios por defecto");
                alert2.showAndWait();

            } else {
                pizzaPorDefecto();
                calcularPrecio();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

y este al método que se le pasa la ruta:

public void cargaPrecios(Path ruta) {

```
    Path archivo = Paths.get(ruta.toString());
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivo.toString()));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda

Comment: Qué es lo que no te funciona??

Comment: Veras lo que pretendo es obtener el path de un archivo seleccionándolo mediante un filechooser y ese path pasarlo como parámetro a un método de otra clase que buscará ese archivo y lo leerá. Lo que ocurre es que cuando obtengo el path y lo paso al método este no reconoce el path. No sé cómo hacerlo ya

Answer (score 1):

Te estas confundiendo con los paths.

**getAbsolutePath()**: Este método de ruta de archivo devuelve la ruta absoluta del archivo. Si el archivo se crea con un nombre de ruta absoluto, simplemente devuelve el nombre de la ruta.
Si el objeto de archivo se crea utilizando una ruta relativa, el nombre de ruta absoluta se resuelve de forma dependiente del sistema. En los sistemas UNIX, un nombre de ruta relativo se convierte en absoluto resolviéndolo con el directorio de usuario actual.

En los sistemas Microsoft Windows, un nombre de ruta relativo se convierte en absoluto resolviéndolo con el directorio actual de la unidad nombrada por el nombre de ruta, si lo hubiera; si no, se resuelve con el directorio de usuarios actual.

Por lo tanto te recomiendo usar esté método.

```
rutaArchivo = file.getAbsolutePath();
//Path ruta = Paths.get(rutaArchivo); //esta linea la eliminamos, por que ya tendríamos el path como string
pizza.cargaPrecios(rutaArchivo);
```

Cambiamos la firma del método `cargaPrecios`

```
public void cargaPrecios( String ruta) {
 //Path archivo = Paths.get(ruta.toString()); Eliminamos esta línea por que ya no lo usaremos puesto que ya tendremos como string la ruta
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        String sCurrentLine;

       // br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivo.toString())); Cambiamos esta linea y le pasaremos el string de ruta
          br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(ruta));
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
    }



   } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: ya había probado esto también, pero el método al que se le pasa el path debe recibir un parámetro tipo path de otro método en otra clase, tampoco me ha funcionado asi

Comment: No te cierres y prueba el código

Comment: No se por que, pero al final ha resultado funcionar, muchas gracias

Comment: @belderan si esta respuesta solucionó el problema, márcala como aceptada.